# LinkedList main program(is it possible to ask user to input the data and stored it in a linkedList way...? )

Tags: java

Below are my question

```
1. In an ArrayList we used below function to ask user to input 20 data, so, how to rewrite this ?
2. Function using the LinkedList method? 
3. Is it possible to ask user to input the data and stored it in a LinkedList way...?
```

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
ArrayList al = new ArrayList(20); 
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); 
Student st; 
String name, id; 

float cgpa; 
for(int i=0; i<20; i++) 
{ 
System.out.println("Name : "); 
name = in.next(); 
System.out.println("ID : "); 
id = in.next(); 
System.out.println("CGPA : "); 
cgpa = in.nextFloat(); 

st = new Student(name, id, cgpa); 
al.add(i,st); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That's all you need:

```
LinkedList al = new LinkedList();
```

Comment: Better you write List al= new LinkedList() it will maintain standard of coding i.e loosly coupling of objects :)

Answer (score 1):

LinkedList also provides [add](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#add%28E%29) method, which both the classes(ArrayList and LinkedList) overrides from [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface. So you just need to change the declaration of your list as mentioned here:

```
List al = new LinkedList();
```

Note the usage of `List` instead of `LinkedList` for reference. This allows to change the implentation list without changing much of your code.

Comment: `LinkedList` doesn't have constructor with the integer parameter.